# Can't run Nvidia PracticalPSM sample in debug mode

Tags: shadows, shadow-mapping, nvidia

I want to add PSM (Prespective shadow map) to my engine but I have problems with that.
I think the problem is somewhere in my math code so I want debug Nvidia PracticalPSM sample and compare the math result in the sample and in my engine so maybe I could find the bug

When I want to compile the sample with VS2005 I get some linker error with DXUT functions maybe it is due to that the static lib DXUT.lib that included is compiled with VS2003 and dose not work probably with VS2005 then I added DXUT source codes from SDK 9.5 to the solution and the sample compiles this time.

When I hit F5 to run the sample it complains about nv_nvb.dll but only release version of nv_nvb.dll is included in the sample and I copied that to debug folder when the program starts it crashes in NVBscene9.cpp line 283.

I don't know why it crashes here.

you can download the sample code from [here](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/SDK/Individual_Samples/DEMOS/Direct3D9/PracticalPSM.zip)

Comment: could you post say, lines 275-283?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.
To fix the DXUT linking errors, for all the functions in DXUT.h that were listed in the error logged, I replaced in their prototype `const WCHAR*` or `LPSTR` by `const unsigned short*`, because this is the type that I found in the DXUT.lib library when running Microsoft dumpbin.exe on it.

However after this stage, I am like you stuck at the `nv_nvb.dll is missing` problem.
It seems that that this is a library used to load `.nvb` files, which I guess is an effect or model file created by NVidia.

If you have 3ds Max installed on your PC, maybe you can try to add the NVidia plug-in described on [this page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_NVBExporterMax.html), it might contain the .dll (I don't have 3ds Max so I could not give it a try).

Good luck !

Alternately, if you run a 32 bits version of Windows you might be able to install the [9.52 version of NVidia SDK](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/NVIDIA_SDK_9.52.0324.0405.exe) (I couldn't because I work on a 64 bits machine).